# multiple indexes in ltxdoc

Tags: indexing, documentation, imakeidx, makeindex

I want to use multiple indexes in ltxdoc. 
But if I use the package imakeidx my defined "General Index" disappears and
I get the standard "Index". Without imakeidx I do get what I want.

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there a workaround?

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\CodelineIndex\EnableCrossrefs

\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}
\IndexPrologue{\section*{General Index}}
\PrintIndex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `imakeidx` package changes the internals of index processing and printing.

First, use `\indexsetup` instead of `\IndexPrologue` and apply the `\makeindex[options=-s gind.ist,title={General index}]` for the general index.

For other indexes apply `\makeindex[name=foo,...]` where `...` stands for other options, eventually.

Say `\printindex` for the default index and `\printindex[foo]` etc. for other indexes

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\CodelineIndex\EnableCrossrefs

\indexsetup{level=\section*}

\makeindex[name=other]
\makeindex[options=-s gind.ist,title={General Index}]

\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacro}\index{mymacro}\index[other]{otherindexentry}
\printindex
\printindex[other]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Christian, I don't understand why my example that shows the problem when I use your suggestion in my real .dtx file is deleted. Of course your example works, I just don't get it to work in the package I am writing. Isn't there anything in my 2nd M_not_WE that you can assist to find a working solution? Or stated otherwise: I really need some help!

Comment: @Jack: As your other question shows you have a totally different setup to this what you posted here. How should I know about those issues? I provided a working solution for your posted document.

Comment: Well I suppose that's the price one pays for making a too minimal WE. As you might have noticed, I rephrased and reposted the question and I am checking that solution now. Regards