# Still problems with multiple indexes in ltxdoc

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, dtx

I refer to the solution that was presented in
[multiple indexes in ltxdoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413101/multiple-indexes-in-ltxdoc/413108#413108)
When I add some lines, it doesn't work anymore. I have the feeling that
something deeper is wrong, but for a start consider this MWE.

1)
The option nonewpage results in no index printed at all (delete the temp
files first if they are already there, otherwise you won't notice this).

2)
The "other" index contains the entry: Test String A , Test String A 1

To me it seems that the imakeidx package and the original indexing in the 
doc package have some communication problems.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
% with option nonewpage no indexes are printed
%\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\CodelineIndex\EnableCrossrefs

\indexsetup{level=\section*}

\makeindex[name=other]
\makeindex[options=-s gind.ist,title={General Index}]

\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacroA}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacroB}\index[other]{\mymacroB}
\def\mymacroA{Test String A}
\def\mymacroB#1{%
  \mymacroA\
  #1
  \mymacroA
}multiple indexes in ltxdoc
%
\newpage
\mymacroB{Test String B}
\printindex
\printindex[other]
\end{document}
```

Comment: With `nonewpage` you must run MakeIndex separately.

Comment: And what about problem 2), where the "other" index contains rubish?

Comment: The `other` index contains `\item \mymacroB, 1`; you need to stringify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems here.

1. With the `nonewpage` option, you need to run MakeIndex manually.
2. You need to stringify `\mymacroB` for insertion in the index (`ltxdoc` does it for its automatically generated index, but not for the others).

Here's an example.

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
% with option nonewpage no indexes are printed
\usepackage[nonewpage]{imakeidx}

\CodelineIndex\EnableCrossrefs

\indexsetup{level=\section*}

\makeindex[name=other]
\makeindex[options=-s gind.ist,title={General Index}]

\begin{document}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacroA}
\DescribeMacro{\mymacroB}\index[other]{mymacroB@\texttt{\string\mymacroB}}
\def\mymacroA{Test String A}
\def\mymacroB#1{%
  \mymacroA\
  #1
  \mymacroA
}multiple indexes in ltxdoc
%
\newpage
\mymacroB{Test String B}
\printindex
\printindex[other]
\end{document}
```

Here's the contents of `jack.ind`:

```
 \begin{theindex} 
 \makeatletter\scan@allowedfalse
{\bfseries\hfil M\hfil}\nopagebreak

  \item \verb*+\mymacroA+\pfill \usage{1}
  \item \verb*+\mymacroB+\pfill \usage{1}

 \end{theindex}
```

The contents of `other.ind`:

```
\begin{theindex}

  \item \texttt{\string\mymacroB}, 1

\end{theindex}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining.
However, when I try to use this in my real project dtx file, I encounter a
more serious problem. I have posted a new question on this 
[https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413624/yet-another-problem-using-imakeidx-in-a-dtx-file]