# Yet another problem using imakeidx in a dtx file

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, dtx

I refer to
[Still problems with multiple indexes in ltxdoc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413501/still-problems-with-multiple-indexes-in-ltxdoc/413565#413565)

The solution given there works for that simple MWE, but in my real project
I encounter a more serious problem. The next M_not_WE shows it. When
I run "pdflatex testidx.dtx" it responds with:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\special@index ...w \immediate \write \@indexfile
  {\string \indexentry
{#1}{...
l.26 % \begin{macro}{\my@macroA}
```

When I comment out the line  "\CodelineIndex" it runs through

What is wrong with my code?

```
% \iffalse
%<*driver>
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\CodelineIndex
\EnableCrossrefs
\indexsetup{level=\section*}
\makeindex[name=other]
\makeindex[options=-s gind.ist,title={General Index}]
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{testidx.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%
% \DescribeMacro{\my@macroA}
% \DescribeMacro{\mymacroB}
%
% \StopEventually{}
%
% \section{Implementation}
%
% \iffalse
%<*package>
% \fi
% \begin{macro}{\my@macroA}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\my@macroA{A}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
% \begin{macro}{\mymacroB}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\def\mymacroB#1{B#1}
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{macro}
%    \begin{macrocode}
\endinput
%    \end{macrocode}
%
% \iffalse
%</package>
% \fi
%
% \Finale
\printindex
\printindex[other]
\endinput
```

Answer (score 1):

There were no responses at all, so I answer my own question.
After some experimenting I found a solution by not using imakeidx at all.
What I did is essentially this (remember that I wanted to have a list of
user commands at the end of the documentation of my package, using ltxdoc):

First I write the commands in a file with some formatting stuff. I thereby use
hyperref to get a clickable index. At the end I read this file to get the 
list.

Prelimary Stuff

```
\newwrite\UCFile
\DeleteShortVerb{\|}
\immediate\openout\UCFile="| sort -d > \jobname.odw
\MakeShortVerb{\|}
```

Read the commands

```
\newcommand\bs{\texttt{\textbackslash}}
\newcommand\usercom[1]{%
  \label{#1}\immediate\write\UCFile{%
    \noexpand\hyperref[#1]{\noexpand\bs#1,
    \thepage\noexpand\newline}}%
}
```

Example of a call

```
\DescribeMacro{\CompassMid}\usercom{CompassMid}
```

Write the file

```
\immediate\closeout\UCFile
\begin{multicols}{3}[\section{List of User Commands}]
  \IfFileExists{\jobname.odw}
     {\noindent\input{\jobname.odw}}
     {\PackageWarning{ODw}{File \jobname.odw not found}}
\end{multicols}
```

Remark

pdflatex must be called with the option --shell-escape